# Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.2.34-36+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Following a fresh Symfony install

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.0.*" my_project
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=8.0.2",
```

and printing out some system info:-

```
php -v
PHP 8.0.25 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2022 18:02:51) ( NTS )
```

and

```
nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Running `symfony console` gives:-

```
symfony console
Composer detected issues in your platform:

Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.2.34-36+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.

PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.2.34-36+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. in /home/code/my_project/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24
```

I'm trying:-

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
There are 6 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.0   70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/php7.1   71        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode
* 6            /usr/bin/php8.1   81        manual mode
```

and this **does** change my CLI version:-

```
php -v
PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2022 17:39:37) (NTS)
```

but composer still complains:-

```
PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform
```

My `PHP` CLI version is now `8.1.12` as above. So which PHP version is composer looking at exactly?

**Edit**

woah, perfect - thanks [image]..

Comment: It's not composer but rather the symfony cli that is having trouble detecting the proper php version to use. `symfony local:php:list` and `symfony local:php:refresh` should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I think the problem occurred because of you have multiple PHP versions on your host. I suggest starting to use containers (docker) that way you can avoid similar problems.